# How to determine whether XAML CheckBox is checked in C++/CX?

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-cx

My XAML code:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="IncludeTextures" Content="Include textures"/>
```

C++/CX:

```
if (IncludeTextures->IsChecked) { // always true (even if Checkbox was not checked)

}
```

The problem is that IsChecked property is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain state(true/false) via "Value" property. ... However, IsChecked property can be NULL when the CheckBox is in "indeterminate" state. So it might be better to fulfill null-check first.

```
if ((IncludeTextures->IsChecked != nullptr) && (IncludeTextures->IsChecked->Value))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Equals() method works:

```
if (IncludeTextures->IsChecked->Equals(true)) {

}
```